# subequations with ranges

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I want to write subequations with ranges, but can't make it look beautiful,
this is what I try to do:

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
      g(z)=A\;\overleftarrow{T_{01}}\;e^{j\kappa_0z}e^{-j\kappa_1z} , &z<0 \label{eq13a}  \\
      g(z)=A\;e^{j\kappa_1(z-z_1)}+A\;\overleftarrow{\Gamma_{10}}\;e^{-j\kappa_1(z+z_1)}, &0<z<z1\label{eq13b}\\
      g(z)=e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}+\Gamma_{in}\;e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}, & z>z1 \label{eq13c}   
    \end{align}
    \end{subequations}
```

and this is what I get, I tried different combinations, but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well you you want, you need two alignment columns. I propose two possibilities and replaced `align` with `alignat` to have full control on the spacing between columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
    \begin{alignat}{2}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
      g(z) & =A\;\overleftarrow{T_{01}}\;e^{j\kappa_0z}e^{-j\kappa_1z} , & & z <0 \label{eq13a} \\
      g(z) & =A\;e^{j\kappa_1(z-z_1)}+A\;\overleftarrow{\Gamma_{10}}\;e^{-j\kappa_1(z+z_1)}, &\qquad 0 < {}& z<z1\label{eq13b}\\
      g(z) & =e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}+\Gamma_{in}\;e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}, & & z >z1 \label{eq13c}
    \end{alignat}
\vskip 4ex
    \begin{alignat}{2}[left = \empheqlbrace\,]
      g(z) & =A\;\overleftarrow{T_{01}}\;e^{j\kappa_0z}e^{-j\kappa_1z} , &z & <0 \label{eq13a} \\
      g(z) & =A\;e^{j\kappa_1(z-z_1)}+A\;\overleftarrow{\Gamma_{10}}\;e^{-j\kappa_1(z+z_1)}, &\qquad 0 & < z<z1\label{eq13b}\\
      g(z) & =e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}+\Gamma_{in}\;e^{-j\kappa_2(z-z_1)}, & z &>z1 \label{eq13c}
    \end{alignat}
    \end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thanks!